# how to create image upload of difference dimensions

Tags: 7, media

I am creating a custom gallery. I require images that are the thumb nail and the big image size. I have custom content type. When i add the image field it allows me to enter the dimensions size. Is there a way for drupal to create 2 images. ie thumb and big image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create two image fields, one for the media image and another one for the thumb, or you could just have one and use different Image Styles ( admin/config/media/image-styles in Drupal 7 ) for both the full and thumbnail. You could even add Image Javascript Crop for more fine-grained control of the thumbnail.

Comment: To complement the answer, there's also a ImageField Focus that enables you to set different focal points for images as it resizes. Quite useful in RWD.

Answer (score -1):

[ImageCache](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache) is what you are looking for. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ...  allows you to setup presets for image processing. If an ImageCache derivative doesn't exist the web server's rewrite rules will pass the request to Drupal which in turn hands it off to ImageCache to dynamically generate the file.